# How to access shared preferences in Composable function?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am migrating from multiple activity compose project to a single activity compose project.

While migrating I have found that I am using shared preferences in multiple screens (Now composable functions)

Passing shared preference object as a parameter to each composable seems tedious is there any better way to do it?

Comment: going with MVVM -> shared preferences is part of Repo . So u should be using it via `ViewModel`. you can inject  shared preferences Object in VM and use it via VM in UI component. In-fact i think this make more sense because u will doing all other stuff with the help of `ViewModel` so its just an add on no need to inject `shared preferences` in Composable functions just the view model ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.

Composable functions' purpose is only to compose the screen and handle UI events (clicks, scrolls, etc.).

You need to use your shared preferences from a view model and expose a state to the composable function, that state will be updated by the shared preferences and will automatically tigger recomposition the screen.

Read [State and Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), especially [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) about states, and [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth) how to use states with view models.

Comment: I see, I am just thinking that as view model now uses a context dependent class will I still be able to write Unti test for it, or will have to write Android test.

Comment: It's your decision - you can either test your `ViewModel` as a unit (create an instance and mess with the functions and fire mock SP events) or real integration test (though I have less experience with those).